# Mongoose - remove _id from lean ( using toJSON() ?)

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I'm having a NODE.JS project using mongoose 5.x

My model have `toJSON` method which removes the `_id` & `__v` fields perfectly

```
mySchema.method("toJSON", function toJSON() {
  const {__v, _id, ...object} = this.toObject();
  return {
    id: _id,
    ...object
  };
});
```

so when fetching data from the db:

```
const data = myModel.findOne({_id: id});
```

I get an object that when serialized to the user:

```
res.json(data);
```

It doesn't contain the `_id` and `__v` fields as required.

The problem is when I use `lean()`:

```
const data = myModel.findOne({_id: id}).lean();
```

the `data` object contains those fields.

I can remove them manually when using `lean`

but I would prefer to find a way to sanitize the data object in both cases with the same mechanism.

any suggestions?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

When `JSON.stringify()` is called on an object, a check if done if it has a property called `toJSON`. It's not specific to Mongoose, as it works on plain objects:

```
const myObj = {
  _id: 123,
  foo: 'bar',
  // `toJSON() {...}` is short for `toJSON: function toJSON() {...}`
  toJSON() {
    // Because "this" is used, you can't use an arrow function.
    delete this._id;
    return this;
  }
};
console.log(JSON.stringify(myObj));
// {"foo":"bar"}
```

Mongoose doesn't have an option to automatically inject a `toJSON` function into objects returned by `lean()`. But that's something you can add.

First, create a function that:

1. Takes an object with properties
2. Listens to when Mongoose runs a `find` query
3. Tells Mongoose that after the query, it should change the result
4. The change: merge the result with the object from step 1.

```
function mergeWithLeanObjects(props) {
  // Return a function that takes your schema.
  return function(schema) {
    // Before these methods are run on the schema, execute a function.
    schema.pre(['find', 'findOne'], function() {
      // Check for {lean:true}
      if (this._mongooseOptions.lean) {
        // Changes the document(s) that will be returned by the query.
        this.transform(function(res) {
          // [].concat(res) makes sure its an array.
          [].concat(res).forEach(obj => Object.assign(obj, props));
          return res;
        });
      }
    });
  };
}
```

Now add it to your schema:

```
mySchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  foo: String
});

mySchema.plugin(mergeWithLeanObjects({
  toJSON() {
    delete this._id;
    delete this.__v;
    return this;
  }
}));
```

Then test it:

```
const full = await myModel.findOne();
const lean = await myModel.findOne().lean();

console.log(full);
// Logs a Mongoose document, all properties.
{ _id: new ObjectId("62a8b39466768658e7333154"), foo: 'bar', __v: 1 }

console.log(JSON.stringify(full));
// Logs a JSON string, all properties.
{"_id":"62a8b39466768658e7333154","foo":"bar","__v":1}

console.log(lean);
// Logs an Object, all properties.
{ _id: new ObjectId("62a8b39466768658e7333154"),
  foo: 'bar', __v: 1, toJSON: [Function: toJSON] }

console.log(JSON.stringify(lean));
// Logs a JSON string, filtered properties.
{"foo":"bar"}
```

---

If you want to re-use the plugin with the same settings on multiple schemas, just save the function that `mergeWithLeanObjects` returns somewhere.

```
// file: clean.js
module.exports = mergeWithLeanObjects({
  toJSON() {
    delete this._id;
    delete this.__v;
    return this;
  }
});

// file: some-schema.js
schema1.plugin(require('./clean.js'));

// file: some-other-schema.js
schema2.plugin(require('./clean.js'));
```

There's also `mongoose.plugin()` to add the function to *all* schemas.

Comment: Ah, I didn't notice this question was bumped by another user and that it's quite old, but I'm sure it'll be of someone else's use some day. ‍♂️

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this is what you want but maybe:

```
const data = myModel.findOne({_id: id}).lean().then(res => {
   delete res._id
   return res
})
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this to retrieve the _id from a document

```
myModel.findOne({_id: id}, function(err, doc) {
   if(err)
     return 'do something with this err'

   console.log(doc._id)
})
```

Comment: this is not related to my question. I want to remove `_id` from `lean()` response.

Comment: @ET-CS oh ok I understand. So I would recommend: creating another variable const filteredData = { name: data.name, location: data.location}. Excluding the _id property